# Indexing Numpy array into Elasticsearch

Tags: python, arrays, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 6.4 along with Python 3. I am processing images and one of the output is a Numpy array. I am trying to index the Numpy array along with other data fields from image analysis into Elasticsearch.  I have three fields:

1. imagename
2. timestamp
3. the Numpy array.

They look as follows:

```
imagename: 123def321_1548492175.jpg 
time_stamp: 1548492175 [
encod:
array([ -1.42405510e-01,   8.58794246e-03,   4.45950478e-02,
        -1.81895699e-02,  -5.53448014e-02,  -1.73689388e-02,
        -4.21237871e-02,  -8.25227201e-02,   1.56264022e-01,
        -3.99713218e-02,   1.60366639e-01,   4.53100577e-02,
        -2.09424138e-01,  -5.07910103e-02,  -4.65360470e-04,
         8.38596523e-02,  -1.19933985e-01,  -1.71518624e-01,
        -1.26374453e-01  ])]
```

The actual array length is much longer.  When I GET my index, it is defined as follows:

```
{
  "g6jy834005er" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "images" : {
        "dynamic" : "false",
        "properties" : {
          "encod" : {
            "type" : "nested"
          },
          "imagename" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "time_stamp" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1548499595840",
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "number_of_replicas" : "0",
        "uuid" : "OP-qab-XRfGQ_oZZEvTClw",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "6050499"
        },
        "provided_name" : "g6jy834005er"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my Python code I am using the following to index the values:

```
doc = {'imagename': name, 'time_stamp': tm,'encod':fenc}
es.index(index=indx, doc_type="images", body=doc)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: ({'imagename': '123def321_1548492174.jpg', 'time_stamp': '1548492174', 'encod': [array([-0.16764426,  0.01966568,  0.04131121, -0.01985365, -0.07606418,....

TypeError("Unable to serialize array([-0.16764426,  0.01966568,  0.04131121, -0.01985365,.....(type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>)",))
```

I am using Elasticsearch only for the last two weeks. I have tried changing the data type of the encoded field to `long`, `nested`,`object`,`text`, etc.  But nothing helped.

Comment: How are you expecting the encod value to be stored in elastic doc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elasticsearch exposes a JSON API, therefore `pyelasticsearch` supports the data types that are valid in a JSON object. Clearly, `numpy.ndarray` is not one among them. 
 
If you had to insert the numpy array, this is a possible work around:

```
encod_np_array = np.array([ -1.42405510e-01,   8.58794246e-03,   4.45950478e-02,
        -1.81895699e-02,  -5.53448014e-02,  -1.73689388e-02,
        -1.26374453e-01  ])
encod_list = encod_np_array.tolist()
doc = {'imagename': name, 'time_stamp': tm,'encod':encod_list}
```

And then call `es.index()`

Comment: Thank you...this helped.

Comment: If it has answered your question, please accept the answer.